# Parsing Json in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a following json string:

```
[ { id: '123', name: 'bla bla', type: 'Source', isLeaf: true },
  { id: '3425', name: 'test test', type: 'Reference', isLeaf: false },
  { id: '12678', name: 'tags', type: 'Source', isLeaf: false },
]
```

I am trying to parse this using JsonSlurper but getting error:

```
groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 5, while reading 'i', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
```

How do I parse it and access the `id:'3425'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Json is invalid, you need to use double quote to delimit strings and you also need to put quotes around the keys in your Json like so:

```
[ { "id": "123", "name": "bla bla", "type": "Source", "isLeaf": true },
  { "id": "3425", "name": "test test", "type": "Reference", "isLeaf": false },
  { "id": "12678", "name": "tags", "type": "Source", "isLeaf": false },
]
```

You can then do:

```
def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( json ).id
assert ids[ 1 ] == '3425'
```

Comment: first I thought so, but http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ tells you that the Json is a valid one. Anyway thank you for the response.

Comment: I suspect jsonviewer.stack.hu is wrong. http://jsonlint.com/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example

Comment: @asp_NewBee: if the jsonviewer app says it is valid then it's wrong. the spec (http://json.org/) is pretty clear.